# SQL Loader - Multiple Files and Grabbing file names

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a folder with over 400K txt files.

With names like

```
deID.RESUL_12433287659.txt_234323456.txt
deID.RESUL_34534563649.txt_345353567.txt
deID.RESUL_44235345636.txt_537967875.txt
deID.RESUL_35234663456.txt_423452545.txt
```

I want to store all the files and their content in the following way:

```
file_name                                      file_content
deID.RESUL_12433287659.txt_234323456.txt       Content 1
deID.RESUL_34534563649.txt_345353567.txt       Content 2
deID.RESUL_44235345636.txt_537967875.txt       Content 3
deID.RESUL_35234663456.txt_423452545.txt       Content 4
```

I tried creating Control file using:

```
LOAD
  DATA 
  INFILE 'deID.RESUL_12433287659.txt_234323456.txt'
  INFILE 'deID.RESUL_34534563649.txt_345353567.txt'
  INFILE 'deID.RESUL_44235345636.txt_537967875.txt'
  INFILE 'deID.RESUL_35234663456.txt_423452545.txt'
  APPEND INTO TABLE TBL_DATA
    EVALUATE CHECK_CONSTRAINTS
    REENABLE DISABLED_CONSTRAINTS
    EXCEPTIONS EXCEPTION_TABLE
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY "" 
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  TRAILING NULLCOLS
  ( 
    FILE_NAME
  )
```

Is there a way I can grab the files names dynamically and specify wildcard in the INFILE so I don't have to mention 400K files one by one in my control file?

Comment: What is OS? Windows or Linux?

Comment: I'm working on Linux - CentOS

Comment: Can merge into one file? `cat *.txt >>all_test.txt` .

Comment: If I merge into one file, then I loose the file names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Create table to hold data/files

```
create table TBL_DATA(file_name varchar2(4000), file_content clob);
```

2) Create load_all.ctl

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE file_list.txt
INSERT INTO TABLE TBL_DATA
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    file_name          char(4000)
  , file_content                   LOBFILE(file_name) TERMINATED BY EOF
)
```

3) Redirect list of file to one file_list.txt
`ls -1 *.txt > file_list.txt`

4) Run `sqlldr user/pass@db control=load_all.ctl`
5)  `load_all.ctl,file_list.txt` and source files should be in the same folder.