# How can I load a XML file to an XMLType column on Oracle 18c with java

Tags: java, xml, oracle, xmltype, oracle18c

I have a complex directory system with millions of xml files which i need to retrieve to an XMLType column in Oracle 18c. I'm working with a java method that is executed by a procedure to re-load this files on this particular table. Since a lot of the of the java libraries were deprecated i'm out of options to solve this issue. The way I had finded to workaround was a tempory table with a CLOB column where I can insert the content from the files and than inside oracle I insert those in the original table using a XMLType(clobVariable). BUT, it doesnt work on files larger then 20k characters.

If anyone can help me I'm more than glad to give more information.
(I'm from Brazil and maybe I didn't made myself clear on the explanation btw)

```
public static void inserirXml() throws Exception{
    try {
        int num_id_nfe;
        String dirArquivo = "";
        String query;
        String queryUpdate;
        String reCheck, insert;

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");

        conn.setAutoCommit(false);               

        query = "SELECT ID_NFE, DSC_CAMINHO_XML FROM DFE_NFE_CAMINHO_XML WHERE FLG_CARREGADO = 0 AND ROWNUM <= 1000";

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        Statement stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
        Statement stmt3 = conn.createStatement();
        Statement stmt4 = conn.createStatement();

        stmt.executeQuery(query);

        ResultSet rset = stmt.getResultSet();

        while(rset.next() == true) {
            try {
                
                num_id_nfe = rset.getInt(1);
                dirArquivo = rset.getString(2);

                byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(dirArquivo));
                
                String xmlString = new String(bytes, "utf-8");
             
                String insertQuery =   "INSERT INTO DFE_NFE_REP_XML_TMP (ID_NFE, XMLCLOB) VALUES(?,?)";

                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
                xmlString = xmlString.substring(1);
                pstmt.setInt(1, num_id_nfe);
                pstmt.setNString(2, xmlString);
                pstmt.execute();

                pstmt.close();

                queryUpdate =   "UPDATE DFE_NFE_CAMINHO_XML SET FLG_CARREGADO = 1 WHERE ID_NFE = " + num_id_nfe + " \n";
                stmt2.executeQuery(queryUpdate);

            }catch(SQLException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage()+" loop");

                stmt2.close();
                throw e;
            }
        }
        insert = "INSERT INTO DFE_NFE_REP_XML (ID_NFE, CONTEUDO) SELECT ID_NFE, XMLType(XMLCLOB) FROM DFE_NFE_REP_XML_TMP";
        stmt4.executeUpdate(insert);

        reCheck = "UPDATE DFE_NFE_CAMINHO_XML SET FLG_CARREGADO = 0 WHERE id_nfe not in (select id_nfe from dfe_nfe_rep_xml) and flg_carregado = 1";
        stmt3.executeQuery(reCheck);

        conn.commit();
        rset.close();           
        stmt.close();
        stmt2.close();
        stmt3.close();
        stmt4.close();
        conn.close();           

    } catch (SQLException x) {
        System.err.println(x.getMessage()+" geral");
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException y) {
        throw y;
    }catch(Exception z) {
        throw z;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] you question with a [MRE] including **YOUR** attempt at a solution as there is a lot of things that you say "don't work" when they should. You can put more than 20k characters in a CLOB and an XMLTYPE [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fc5ae01e09503a4d7ffa7af5c2440420). Java is capable of streaming a file into a CLOB and then you can create an XMLTYPE from it.

Comment: Also, see [this similar question about loading thousands of files to a CLOB column in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54783948/sql-loader-multiple-files-and-grabbing-file-names) using SQL*Loader.

Comment: @kfinity This isn't nothing like my problem